# What happens when a Window service is started?

Tags: python, windows, service, multiprocessing

I am writing a windows service with python and using pyinstaller to package it into an executable. The python script will contain the service subclass with necessary overridden methods as well as a MessageServer class for some socket communication and to display simple message boxes. I have the MessageServer seperate because of the interactive services restrictions in Windows. What I'm trying to figure out is when you start a service from the GUI or from the CLI (net start ) what happens? does it just execute the service's .exe with start argument or does it just access a portion of the code within?

I'll post the code I'm using but keep in mind that this is nowhere near where I want to be for the real thing... just using it to test some ideas.

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import win32timezone
import win32api
import win32con

import sys
import time
import random

import multiprocessing

svc_name = "testSvc"
TIMEOUT = 6000


class TesterService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = svc_name
    _svc_display_name_ = "test service"
    _svc_description_ = "This service is for testing purposes"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        global sm
        while True:
            stop_signal = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, TIMEOUT)

            try:
                if stop_signal == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                    break
                else:
                    if sm == 0:
                        sm = 1
            except RuntimeError as details:
                print(details)


class MessageServer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._messages_ = ["msg-1", "msg-2", "msg-3", "msg-4", "msg-5"]
        self._serve_msg_(self._messages_)

    def _serve_msg_(self, msgs):
        t = 0
        while t < 36:
            time.sleep(6)
            t += 6
            win32api.MessageBox(
                None,
                msgs[random.randint(0, 4)],
                "test message box",
                win32con.MB_ICONHAND
            )


class MsgSrvProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, name="Ptest"):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        MessageServer()


sm = 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize(svc_name, None)
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(TesterService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()

    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TesterService)
    c = 0
    while c < 18:
        c += 6
        if sm == 1:
            p1 = MsgSrvProcess()
            p1.start()
            p1.join()
        else: sm = 1
        time.sleep(6)
    print("exiting")
```

Comment: This is documented under [Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685141.aspx).

Comment: As far as Windows is concerned, the executable is launched as normal, with whatever command line arguments were registered when the service was created.  The executable must immediately make contact with the service control manager.  (I would *guess* that's what `ServiceFramework.__init__` does.)